# click eventHandler, attached with jQuery, does not fire

Tags: jquery

I have a Problem with my jQuery code.

When I click a Name in the list, nothing happens, on the second click the rect is changing the color, the same problem is still there until every List-Tag is clicked twice.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var blankMap = $('#path1, #path2, #path3');
    var bgtext = $('#1, #2, #b3');


    $(function () {

        $("a").click(function () {
            var aID = $(this).attr("id");

            $("#" + aID).on("click", function () {
                $(bgtext).css('background-color', 'white');
                $(blankMap).attr("fill", "#ECECEC");
                $("#path" + aID).attr("fill", "#C8D538");
            });


        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2rg1sujb/

Dont know how to fix this... =/

Comment: `.click()` is functionally equivalent to `.on('click')`.  In other words, you have a `click` handler inside of another `click` handler.  The inner `click` handler is disabled until the outer `click` occurs.  The whole thing makes no sense, but the observed behavior is exactly as expected.

Comment: What's the goal of `$("#" + aID).on("click", function () {...`?

Comment: Also `$(function()..` is functionally equivalent to `$(document).ready(function()...`, so you have a DOM ready even handler inside of a DOM ready event handler.

Comment: ah, sparky, thanks for your answer, just deleted the inner click handler..

Comment: If i did something wrong, I'm  sorry about this, but my english is not so good and in german there is no platform like this.. But thank you all for helping.

Comment: Not a problem.  Please, just take some time to study this guide... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/2rg1sujb/1/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var blankMap = $('#path1, #path2, #path3');
    var bgtext = $('#1, #2, #b3');
    $("a").click(function () {
      var aID = $(this).attr("id");
          $('#1, #2, #b3').css('background-color', 'white');
          $('#path1, #path2, #path3').attr("fill", "#ECECEC");
          $("#path" + aID).attr("fill", "#C8D538");
          return(false);

    });
  });
```

You have click in click event